# Http4s circe can not decode children

Tags: scala, circe, http4s, http4s-circe

I have error model like:

```
sealed trait HttpError {
    val msg: String
    val cause: String
  }

  final case class HttpDecodingError(cause: String) extends HttpError {
    override val msg: String = "Decoding error"
  }

  final case class HttpInternalServerError(msg: String, cause: String) extends HttpError
  case object HttpUnauthorizedError extends HttpError {
    override val msg: String = "Invalid credentials"
    override val cause: String = ""
  }
  final case class HttpBadRequestError(msg: String, cause: String) extends HttpError
```

in my route I generate http error type based on this model ie:

```
.foldM(
          {
            case error: HttpDecodingError       => BadRequest(error.asInstanceOf[HttpError])
            case error: HttpInternalServerError => InternalServerError(error.asInstanceOf[HttpError])
            case HttpUnauthorizedError          => Unauthorized(withChallenge("Invalid credentials"))
            case error: HttpBadRequestError     => BadRequest(error.asInstanceOf[HttpError])
          },
          Ok(_)
        )
```

but problem is that I need to add this asInstanceOf, otherwise circe does not see encoder.
My encoder looks like:

```
implicit val encodeHttpError: Encoder[HttpError] = (error: HttpError) =>
    Json.obj(("msg", Json.fromString(error.msg)), ("cause", Json.fromString(error.cause)))
```

is there a way to avoid doing asInstanceOf there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use encoder for `HttpError` for it's subclasses, because `Encoder` is invariant (it would work if it would be covariant).

One solution you could use is to define encoder using parametrized `def` instead of `val`:

```
implicit def encodeHttpError[E <: HttpError]: Encoder[E] = (error: E) =>
  Json.obj(
    ("msg", Json.fromString(error.msg)),
    ("cause", Json.fromString(error.cause))
  )
```

This way you'd have instance of encoder for all subtypes of `HttpError` as well as for `HttpError`.